# TYPO3 I can no longer use new extensions

Tags: typo3

After several updates to my TYPO3 site (now on 4.6.4) i can no longer install new extensions. Extension manager fetches them but i cannot actually use them (they don't show up in the module list when inserting a content element).

The rest of the site works well and i was even able to update an existing extension.

Any idea how to fix this error ? Is there a way to uninstall and reinstall just the Extension Manager ? I've tried to delete table sys_ter but it makes no difference. I'm hesitant to delete the table cache_extension.

EDIT : removed database error message as pgampe suggested it's not an issue. also : reformulated the issue for clarity

EDIT2 : upgrading to typo3 4.7 solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix it with `Install tool`, select `Database Analyser` next `COMPARE` and you will see which tables are missing, you can add them by selecting the appropriate checkboxes.

Be careful about removing suggested tables and/or fields, make sure that they aren't used really.

Of course I advice to create full dump before the operation.

Comment: I already used Database Analyser and it mostly showed tables and fields that were due for deletion. The current message is "Table and field definitions are OK". The only warning is "Extra tables in the database"

Comment: Then everything is fine. The DB layer in TYPO3 can not handle all MySQL specific definitions. If others do not care about other DBs, then they put stuff in the table definitions file that can only be handled by MySQL. When TYPO3 then compares what it thinks to be there with the actual definition, then it turns out that this does not match. Nothing to worry about.